# simpledialog.SimpleDialog in python with 2 inputsH

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, tkinter

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain a simpledialog.SimpleDialog in python with 2 inputs. The documentation is not clear on this and I could not find any information on this online.

The end result I would like to get is something on the lines of this:
An input box with 2 lines one for each variable

```
|---------------------|
|Input 1 | ' text abc'|
|---------------------|
|Input 2 | ' Text fgh'|
|---------------------|
```

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're after something like this:

[image]

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) explains how to do *everything*, which is much more than you need right now.

You need the label widget, the entry widget, the button widget and the packer geometry manager.

A good tutorial for you might be [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/), and this answer is based partly on his code:

```
#### Save this as dual_input.py ####
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import Tk, Text, TOP, BOTH, X, N, LEFT, RIGHT
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Entry, Button

# Good habit to put your GUI in a class to make it self-contained
class SimpleDialog(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self allow the variable to be used anywhere in the class
        self.output1 = ""
        self.output2 = ""
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Simple Dialog")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)

        lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="Input 1", width=6)
        lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.entry1 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=self.output1)
        self.entry1.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        frame2 = Frame(self)
        frame2.pack(fill=X)

        lbl2 = Label(frame2, text="Input 2", width=6)
        lbl2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.entry2 = Entry(frame2)
        self.entry2.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        frame3 = Frame(self)
        frame3.pack(fill=X)

        # Command tells the form what to do when the button is clicked
        btn = Button(frame3, text="Submit", command=self.onSubmit)
        btn.pack(padx=5, pady=10)

    def onSubmit(self):

        self.output1 = self.entry1.get()
        self.output2 = self.entry2.get()
        self.quit()

def main():

    # This part triggers the dialog
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = SimpleDialog()
    root.mainloop()
    # Here we can act on the form components or
    # better yet, copy the output to a new variable
    user_input = (app.output1, app.output2)
    print(app.output1)
    # Get rid of the error message if the user clicks the
    # close icon instead of the submit button
    # Any component of the dialog will no longer be available
    # past this point
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass
    # To use data outside of function
    # Can either be used in __main__
    # or by external script depending on
    # what calls main()
    return user_input

# Allow dialog to run either as a script or called from another program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    follow_on_variable = main()
    # This shows the outputs captured when called directly as `python dual_input.py`
    print(follow_on_variable)
#### End of dual_input.py code dialog code file ####

### Example of using from code file as opposed to ###
### calling directly                              ###
### Save this as i_do_work_here.py                ###
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import dual_input

received_inputs = dual_input.main()

calculated = int(received_inputs[0]) * int(received_inputs[1])
print(str(calculated))
### End of i_do_work_here.py  ###
```

Comment: Hello.
First of all, thanks for you reply!

You code run however I cannot get the output 1 and output 2 outside as independent variables. 

Would you be so kind as to teach me how to do that?

Comment: Add a return statement to main() to recover user_input.

Comment: It did not work. Possibly because there is no place to return to, since I'm quitting before returning. If I put the return be return statment before try: the window will not close

Comment: Are you running the script directly or via import? It works on my end when I run it directly i.e. it prints the outputs. If you are calling it via an import, you need to show what you are doing so we can identify what is wrong with it.

Comment: The return statement cannot be before the try statement as the `root.destroy()` in the try statement is required to close the form. The return must be the last statement in `main()`.